# Wrong emblem appearing in chat

Tags: bug, chat, avatar

When I appear in chat, my icon is currently showing as a pink diagram, instead of my normal green. Can this be rectified as as soon as possible, please. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Here's some screengrabs:

Whole screen:

[image]

Top right-hand corner:

[image]

Bottom left-hand corner:

[image]

Comment: The icon next to your username appears to be green 'spots' on a white(ish) background. Time reference: your question was asked 27 minutes ago and edited 16 minutes ago.

Comment: Quite likely this is a cache issue. Are you using Firefox (which has been known to have similar problems) or Internet Explorer (which will happily use an incorrect cached image because of its aggressive caching policy) or another browser? A screenshot would definitely help.

Comment: @Lawrence, Andrew.  It's only happening in chat. Not on the main sites. It's happening in IE, Firefox and Safari.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I've edited in some screenshots.

Comment: Interesting. I'm not seeing that: http://i.imgur.com/wSplc1S.png but if it's a caching issue it shouldn't affect more than one browser identically.

Comment: @Araucaria Can you pop over to the main [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95/english-language-usage)? I'm there now and can check.

Comment: This is related to all the other wrong gravatar bugs. See my question and its answer [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/283656/323179).

Comment: Related: [Moderator election ballot: Different default images for candidates](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283642/moderator-election-ballot-different-default-images-for-candidates).